# Does forceUpdate not work like I think it does?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Take the very simple react.js app [I created here](http://jsbin.com/juficu/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
  <main></main>
  <section>
    <input value="abc" />
  </section>
```

..

```
data = note: ""
setNote = -> data.note = $('input').val()

display = React.createFactory React.createClass render: ->
  React.DOM.div null, "The note is:", @props.note

setNote()
rootComponent = React.render display(data), document.querySelector('main')

$('input').on 'keyup', -> 
  setNote()
  rootComponent.forceUpdate()
```

by my understanding [of the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) when I keyup on the input it should set `data.note` (which I've verified that it does) and since `display`'s `render` method uses the `note` property, calling `rootComponent.forceUpdate` should force display to re-render and mirror the text in the input.

However it still only shows the original value of `data.note`. Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Note that I'm aware that typically this is the sort of thing that you might use flux or reflux on, and while I appreciate any links to good tutorials on these, this is for a one-off and I'm trying to stick close to the metal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [setProps](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setprops). This passes updated data to a component and triggers a re-render.

Try:

```
$('input').on 'keyup', -> 
  setNote()
  rootComponent.setProps(data)
```

React must not by passing data by reference, meaning when your `data` variable is updated the component keeps the original implementation passed to it.

---

**Edit:** To answer the question of what would you use `forceUpdate` for, consider the following altered example:

```
data = note: ""
setNote = -> data.note = $('input').val()

display = React.createFactory React.createClass render: ->
    React.DOM.div null, "The note is:", data.note

setNote()
rootComponent = React.render (display()), document.querySelector('main')

$('input').on 'keyup', -> 
  setNote()
  rootComponent.forceUpdate()
```

Notice now that the data is not passed to the component, but rather referenced globally. `forceUpdate` should be used when your render method includes data from outside the scope of react, and the decision for when the component needs to be re-rendered is deferred to an outside source.

Comment: I see and that works. So in the interest of answering the specific question - when *would* you want to use `forceUpdate` then?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address `forceUpdate`. Hope this helps to clarify things.